# Extruding along normals actually extrudes laterally

Tags: extrude

Using 3.1.

Trying to extrude hole borders along normals to give them some depth. While the object is a deformed plane obtained applying a `Shrinkwrap` modifier, vertex normals seems correct:

[image]

However extrusion with `extrude along normals` is done laterally, in the plane, similar to scaling in plane (extruding holes individually gives the same result):

[image]

I'm sure I've forgotten to set something, but I can't see what...

(this is part of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYEaY6RTUzc), at 44:39)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've looked at the moment in video to understand that is wrong.

From the hotkeys you can see that he pressed <kbd>G</kbd> because extruding worked like you show.

[image]

So he used extrude to make a new ring of edges, and then moved it using the regular grab tool.

Comment: You are right on the tutorial (and in that case there is no need to use 'along normals', as a simple extrude will be enough). I'm surprised, extruding along normals should follow normals, the documentation is very poor (*Extrusion and offset will be locked in to only move along the local normals of the selected mesh*). See also [Extrude and Move on Normals does not move vertices or edges on normals](https://developer.blender.org/T57681). Now if this is not the correct tool to use for the purpose of extruding along the normals, do you know how can this be done?

Comment: Along normal is Alt+S, this works strange with edges... Probably a face  only tool

Comment: Mesh>Transform>Shrink/Fatten (Alt-S) doesn't extrude but [moves vertices along normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/shrink-fatten.html?highlight=shrink%20flatten), that's a good help, Extrude followed by this tool should do an actual extrusion along normals. Well (after checking) actually it doesn't as vertex normals are again equal to vertex positions, as mentioned in the bug report I linked earlier. The result is a scaling operation about the object origin. I give up!